# Is there a way to find() a random element from an object containing specific values

Tags: javascript

I've got an object containing gyms with their available equipment:

```
        const gyms = [
  {
    "name": "gym1",
    "equipmentAvailable": ["nothing"]
  },
  {
    "name": "gym2",
    "equipmentAvailable": ["jump rope","stationary bike","barbell"]
  },
  {
    "name": "gym3",
    "equipmentAvailable": ["kettlebell","dumbbell"]
  },
  {
    "name": "gym4",
    "equipmentAvailable": ["barbell","kettlebell","jump rope"]
  }
]
```

I've also got a list of the equipment I need for my next workout (that's then converted to a Set):

```
const availableNeeded = ["barbell","jump rope"]

const equipmentSet = new Set(availableNeeded);
```

Currently I'm using .find() to pull the first gym that matches my equipment needs with:

```
const filteredWorkouts = gyms.find(workout => (
  workout.equipmentAvailable.some(equipment => equipmentSet.has(equipment))
))

console.log(filteredWorkouts)
```

Naturally, this always returns gym2 as it's the first gym to match the needed equipment. *However*, sometimes I want to switch it up and go to gym4 as it *also* has the needed equipment but find() won't deliver.

How would I randomize the gym output so that it could spit out either gym2 *or* gym4?

Comment: Your edited post using `workout.equipmentAvailable.every` doesn't return anything - the `.find` won't work like that. Did you perhaps mean to do `availableNeeded.every(equip => gym.equipmentAvailable.includes(equip))`?

Comment: Indeed I did. My apologies - I'm still fairly new to this. Your answer is extremely helpful, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.filter` instead of `.find` to get an array of possible matches, then get a random element from the array:

```js
const gyms = [
  {
    "name": "gym1",
    "equipmentAvailable": ["nothing"]
  },
  {
    "name": "gym2",
    "equipmentAvailable": ["jump rope","stationary bike","barbell"]
  },
  {
    "name": "gym3",
    "equipmentAvailable": ["kettlebell","dumbbell"]
  },
  {
    "name": "gym4",
    "equipmentAvailable": ["barbell","kettlebell","jump rope"]
  }
];
const availableNeeded = ["barbell","jump rope"];
const filteredWorkouts = gyms.filter(gym => (
  availableNeeded.every(equip => gym.equipmentAvailable.includes(equip))
));
const result = filteredWorkouts[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredWorkouts.length)];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This code returns any gym that has at least 1 matching equipment. You should use `every` array method instead of `some`.

Comment: OP originally used `.some`, so I coped that logic, it looks like he edited the post. Not entirely sure what he's looking for, I'll ask